# Why doesn't a pinhole camera result in blurred images due to diffraction?

Tags: optics, diffraction

Shouldn't a pinhole camera image be super blurry due to diffraction? Why does it work?

Comment: this may help http://feuerbacher.net/photo/Pinhole/Pinhole.html